# How to serialize into JSON objects nested within other objects?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have two objects, with the first one having an instance of the second as a Property.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumber PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneNumber
{
    public int DialingCode { get; set; }
    public int AreaCode { get; set; }
    public int FirstThree { get; set; }
    public int LastFour { get; set; }
}
```

My objective is to, using Newtonsoft.Json, serialize my `Person` class into a string of JSON where the `PhoneNumber` Property is also serialized, like this:

```
"Person": {
    "FirstName": "String",
    "LastName": "String",
    "Age": "Int",
    "PhoneNumber": {
        "DialingCode": "Int",
        "AreaCode": "Int",
        "FirstThree": "Int",
        "LastFour": "Int"
    }
}
```

but I'm running into a snag where the JsonConverter I'm using only serializes the `Person` object, and in place of the `PhoneNumber` Property just displays the name of the object, like this:

```
"Person": {
    "FirstName": "String",
    "LastName": "String",
    "Age": "Int",
    "PhoneNumber": "PhoneNumber"
}
```

And below is the code for my custom JsonSerializer:

```
public class CustomJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly Type[] _types;

    public CustomJsonConverter(params Type[] types)
    {
        _types = types;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return _types.Any(t => t == objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
            return;
        }
        var properties = value.GetType().GetProperties();
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName(property.Name);
            var propertyName = property.PropertyType.Name == "Int32"  ? "Int" : property.PropertyType.Name;
            serializer.Serialize(writer, propertyName);
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

Is there any way I could serialize an object, and all of the objects that are contained within it?

Comment: Why are you using a custom converter at all?

Comment: The custom converter is being used to display the data type of each of the properties in the JSON (i.e `"FirstName": "String"`).

Comment: Ok, I see that - but that is not serialization.  `"FirstName": "Ziggy"` is serializer output - the value of a property not the type

Comment: @Delfino but you don’t need it! It can handle conversion of custom properties too.

Comment: @DavideVitali I'm not entirely sure what you're talking about.

Comment: Ok sorry I got I now, you actually want the type as value of the property...

Comment: Yeah, having the property's type is useful to me for creating JSON templates for DTOs I'm using in my API project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can just serialize it with one call

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
```

and that is all.

Comment: I found out that in my `Person` object's constructor I wasn't instantiating the `PhoneNumber` Property (i.e. `PhoneNumber = new PhoneNumber()`).